# Tooltip display issue on Microsoft Edge when word length is >50

Tags: html, tooltip, microsoft-edge

Edge doesn’t display tooltips in the desired way on one particular case where a single word(longer than ~50chars) without spaces is not displayed fully. As you can see in my code, I have a title attribute with value as 3 words(set of characters without space), first one having more than 50 chars. The tootlip on edge would show the first fifty and then shows ellipsis ...

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123 second word">
 123...</span>;
```

Expected result would be to show the title value as is as tooltip which is

12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123 second word

Actual result is

12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890... second word

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HGphAnT

Comment: I try to make a test using your above code. I find that tool tip is working fine with Edge. Here is my testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/YCqzTL1t/95.gif I suggest you to again make a test with new HTML page. If issue persist than try to post your testing result. I will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: https://gph.is/2VapwEz Here is the link to the gif of the same html (<span>) of exact same code in the question. I am using Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0

Comment: At present, I am available with 42.17134.1.0 version in which it is showing the whole  word. It can be possible that something got changed in the new update which shows the very long word with (...). 50 characters are too long for any word. I am not aware about any word have length of 50 characters. I will try to test with new version and if it is producible than I will try to find any solution or work around for it.

Comment: The requirement is such that we have IDs etc. which occur with >50chars.